# how to get string array from struct array swift4?

Tags: swift

```
let exercises = [
  Exercises(category:"Sports", name:"Bowling", x_seed:[125,155,185], y_seed:[3.00, 3.73, 4.43], hasMult:false),
  Exercises(category:"Sports", name:"Water Polo", x_seed:[125,155,185], y_seed:[10.00, 12.40,14.80], hasMult:false),
  Exercises(category:"Sports", name:"Handball", x_seed:[125,155,185], y_seed:[12.00, 14.87, 17.77], hasMult:false),
  Exercises(category:"Sports", name:"Dancing", x_seed:[125,155,185], y_seed:[3.00, 3.73, 4.43], hasMult:true),
  Exercises(category:"Sports", name:"Frisbee", x_seed:[125,155,185], y_seed:[3.00, 3.73, 4.43], hasMult:false),
  Exercises(category:"Sports", name:"Volleyball", x_seed:[125,155,185], y_seed:[3.00, 3.73, 4.43], hasMult:false),
  Exercises(category:"Sports", name:"Archery", x_seed:[125,155,185], y_seed:[3.50, 4.33, 5.17], hasMult:false),
  Exercises(category:"Sports", name:"Golf", x_seed:[125,155,185], y_seed:[3.50, 4.33, 5.17], hasMult:true)
]
```

This is my struct array. I want to print all the names like below in swift4:

```
Bowling,water polo, volleyball,dancing,Archery etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using the `map` function:

```
let names = exercises.map { $0.name }
```

If you need one string, separated by commas, then:

```
let names = exercises
   .map { $0.name }
   .joined(separator: ",")
```

Comment: thanks, it works well.